# RecyclerView notifydatasetchanged result in crash

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

## Update - 07/03/2018

Looks like the problem might be due to my lazy loading of the `list`:
In my list I might have `pictures, spinners, multispinners,` ...
To increase performance I load the datasources or the pictures in `background`, so I don't have to stop my UI for it.

Looks like that if I refresh the datasource too fast, while those components are loading, it cause the error.

Still trying, I will keep this updated.

---

I have a RecyclerView filled up with an Adapter. After performing some operations, I change the datasource by clicking on another list item and I notify the adapter like below:

To be sure I also stopped scrolling:
(The updateDataSource method just refresh the ArrayList I have in my adapter)

```
private void setupList() {
    //questi sono quelli che non hanno dipendenze.
    try {
        if (interventionActivityAdapter == null) {
            interventionActivityAdapter = new InterventionActivityAdapter(InterventoAttivitaFragment.this,
                    getActivity(),
                    new IReturnBoolToParent() {
                        public void onResult(boolean b) {
                            getActivity().getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
                            parseGetActivities();
                        }
                    },
                    myNonRealmActivitieAdapterPojos);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(interventionActivityAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        } else {
            //listState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
            mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
            mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
            interventionActivityAdapter.updateDataSource(myNonRealmActivitieAdapterPojos);
            interventionActivityAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            getActivity().getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
            //mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Errore durante l'analisi delle attività.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    pbSyncState.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This is my adapter

```
public class InterventionActivityAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InterventionActivityFieldViewHolder> {

    private Activity ctx;
    private Fragment f;
    private ArrayList<InterventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo> interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos;
    private IReturnBoolToParent iReturnBoolToParent;

    public InterventionActivityAdapter(Fragment f,
                                       Activity ctx,
                                       IReturnBoolToParent iReturnBoolToParent,
                                       ArrayList<InterventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo> interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos) {
        this.f = f;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.iReturnBoolToParent = iReturnBoolToParent;
        this.interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos = interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos;
    }

    public void updateDataSource(ArrayList<InterventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo> interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos) {
        this.interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos = interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos.get(position).getType() == RuntimeHelper.ActivityChildType.PADRE) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public InterventionActivityFieldViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (ctx == null) {
            ctx = (Activity) parent.getContext();
        }
        View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
                .inflate(viewType == 1 ? R.layout.item_interventionactivity : R.layout.item_interventionactivity_son, parent, false);
        return new InterventionActivityFieldViewHolder(inflatedView, f, ctx, false, iReturnBoolToParent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(InterventionActivityFieldViewHolder holder, int position) {
        InterventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo;
        interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo = interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos.get(position);
        holder.initInterventionActivityField(interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos != null ? interventionActivityFieldAdapterPojos.size() : 0;
    }
}
```

I use a custom viewHolder, but it is more than 60k characters and I can't post it here.

The bug arrives with the notifyDataSetChanged()'s call.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.netribe.business.gridwaywfm.netribe, PID: 25935
     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'long android.widget.Adapter.getItemId(int)' on a null object reference
         at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:931)
         at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:920)
         at android.widget.AdapterView.access$300(AdapterView.java:55)
         at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:890)
         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5621)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out..

## Note:

I noticed that the crash is coming only if the item that fires the notifydatasetchanged is half (or more) scrolled away.. it might help

### Note_2

I noticed also that if I debug the code, the app will not crash.
If I do not debug, it randomly crash.

### Personal consideration

I tried to debug and to change a lot of stuffs, but the problem persisted. The best way to make it appen is to change the item that update the source and then hysterically swipe up and down the list. This will cause the errore once every 6-7 tries..

Comment: Post the activity's or fragmetn's code also please...

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan I only do Realm queries or some non-related logics, should I add it anyway?

Comment: Btw i noticed that it occur if the item that fires the notifyDataSetChanged is half scrolled away and half in the view

Comment: Are you setting the adapter multiple times?

Comment: @LevonPetrosyan I added the full relevant method, it should also answer your question; I set the adapter only once, if it is already present I just update the datasource

Comment: Try to avoid to "catch everything", like on this line `catch (Exception ex)`. This usually means you're not sure of what can go wrong on that part of the code. Try to catch specific exceptions that might be thrown on that area of the code.

Comment: @Mauker true, you are absolutely right, thanks for the tip! I added this "catch everything" because I'm really out of my mind for this problem and I tried the simplest solution.. but unfortunatly this is not going to my catch :(